# centre align with 3 div tags inline

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have 3 div tags inside a parent div. I want to align Every thing in centre.

```
div-1 - Left Arrow link to prev image set.
div-2 - It will have multiple images.
div-3 - Right Arrow link to next image set.
```

I am doing the following:

```
#container { text-align: center; }
#div-1 { float: left; }
#div-2 { display: inline; }
#div-3 { float: right; }
```

With this Images are displaying in center as required. But Left arrow and right arrow is displaying at extreme left and extreme right of the screen.

How to display them just besides of images?

Comment: are the child divs has fixed width.?

Comment: floats will float them very far away. Instead of floating, try having them _all_ as inline blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use display: inline-block; like this:

```
#container{ 
    text-align: center;
}
#div-1, #div-2, #div-3{
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Then if you want to center them also vertically you could add vertical-align: center; to your child divs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to do this utilising a new feature in CSS called `flexbox`. Using it, here's what your CSS would look like:

```
#container { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: horizontal; 
}
#div-1 {
    flex: 1; order: 0; 
}
#div-2 {
    flex: 1; order: 1; 
}
#div-3 { 
    flex: 1; order: 2; 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Using this displaying the right arrow in next line. Not inline. Also left arrow is still at extreme left.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the position of the container div using margin.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftArrow"><</div>
    <div id="images">Images</div>
    <div id="rightArrow">></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
//margin : top right bottom left;

div{
    display : inline;
}

#container{ 
    margin : 0px 0px 0px 30%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/Cxj7A/)

Answer (score 0):

Specify a width value for the container, otherwise 100% of screen width would be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: 
[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nightstalker22/T7p2F/)

```
div > div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to align markup elements via `CSS`, but using the tabular display is the simplest one IMO, that also works on most of the browsers.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bm8vk/)

Hope it has helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without watching how the divs are really displayed, but with your description My first try would be:

```
#div-1 { float: left; margin: 0 0 0 10%}
#div-2 { display: inline;}
#div-3 { float: right; margin: 0 10% 0 0}
```

Play with the 10% to get the position you want.

This will cause troubles if your content is responsive. Might have to work with div-2 witdh for that.